# How dow I configure Org Mode elisp link dialog?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have written an org-mode model of a Mac keyboard which uses links to identify elisp functions associated with a given key and optional modifier.  It occurred to me that I could use the org-mode external elisp link type so that when I click on the text, the code will execute to describe the key binding `(describe-function)`.  And it works, but with a nasty side effect that I get prompted with an ugly dialog to approve executing the code.  I totally understand that this is default behavior but I am hoping this behavior can be easily overridden by an org-mode configuration setting so that "yes" is effectively always selected.  Perhaps the answer is to create a custom protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to set are:

```
;; enable prompt-free code running
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil        ;; for running code blocks
      org-confirm-elisp-link-function nil   ;; for elisp links
      org-confirm-shell-link-function nil)  ;; for shell links
```

Comment: This definitely solved my issue.  Nicely done.  But it reveals another issue: two buffers are popped up, one shows the *Help* function.  The other appears to be an artifact of elisp link processing.  I'll post another question, if necessary, to deal with this behavior.